# What are the values of output $g_i$ in Bengio's paper "Taking on the Curse of Dimensionality in Joint Distributions Using Neural Networks"

Tags: neural-networks, joint-distribution, graphical-model

Figure 2 of Bengio's paper ["Taking on the Curse of Dimensionality in Joint Distributions Using Neural Networks"](http://www.iro.umontreal.ca/~lisa/pointeurs/jdm.pdf) 
describes a neural network structure for estimating a joint probability distribution.

[image]

**Question**: What are the values $g_i$ used during the training of the model?